# camel-ftp: destination filename encoding error

Tags: character-encoding, apache-camel, camel-ftp

developing on windows 10. Using Win10 IIS FTP server. create a camel context to transfer ftp files. Problem comes out on Chinese Files transfer. The Chinese file in destination path garbled.

I try to add charset(ios-8859-1, utf-8, gb2312 ...) param in both from() & to() URI, not works.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        try {
            from("ftp://127.0.0.1:2121?binary=true&charset=windows-1252&delay=5s&delete=true&passiveMode=true&recursive=true")
            .to("file://E:/ftp_copy/local?charset=utf-8")   
            .log("Downloaded file ${file:name} complete."); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

some log:

```
15:21:08.321 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ftp://127.0.0.1:2121] DEBUG o.a.c.c.f.FileOperations - [writeFileByReaderWithCharset,462] - Using Reader to write file: E:\ftp_copy\local\ÖÐÎÄ°¦°¦.txt with charset: utf-8

15:21:08.322 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ftp://127.0.0.1:2121] DEBUG o.a.c.c.f.GenericFileProducer - [writeFile,282] - Wrote [E:\ftp_copy\local\ÖÐÎÄ°¦°¦.txt] to [file://E:%5Cftp_copy%5Clocal?charset=utf-8]

15:21:08.324 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ftp://127.0.0.1:2121] INFO  route1 - [log,159] - Downloaded file ÖÐÎÄ°¦°¦.txt complete.

15:21:08.325 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ftp://127.0.0.1:2121] DEBUG o.a.c.c.f.GenericFileOnCompletion - [onCompletion,75] - Done processing file: RemoteFile[ÖÐÎÄ°¦°¦.txt] using exchange: Exchange[ID-LAPTOP-7L49H3A5-1548141666835-0-1]

15:21:08.325 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - ftp://127.0.0.1:2121] DEBUG o.a.c.c.f.r.FtpOperations - [deleteFile,232] - Deleting file: ÖÐÎÄ°¦°¦.txt
```

Comment: the file content is stored in correct encoding, but filename garbled

Comment: The charset settings you made only effect the encoding of the file contents. Not the encoding of the file name. For the latter the file system in use and potentially settings for that file system are relevant. I would not know how to influence the behavior of the file system in such a case.